# Is it a good practice to write helper functions in controller itself

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am new to Microsoft ASP.NET MVC framework. I am working on MVC project where I have a controller. It has various ActionResult methods. Also, it needs several helper functions. Can I write them in controller itself? Please guide me.

Comment: I suggest you to write your helpers as Class libraries. That will make your code more structed and you can make dll to use the same helpers at other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not best practice.As helper function needs to be define/implemented in static class. So it is better to to have standalone seprate helper class.

Comment: That is not a good thing to give a negative vote to a new comer in the community without any reason...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: it depends. First of all it is not clear what do you mean with helper functions.

- if you are talking about ASP.NET MVC HTML Helpers, it is better to move them to separate class. [Tutorial how to create and use them](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs).
- if you are talking about general helper functions that evaluate something, of course you may leave them in controller, move to the base controller or move to separate class or library (depeneds on context). You may check implementation of standard System.Web.Mvc.Controller, there are a lot of methods and properties in it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think controllers are only supposed to have action methods and nothing else. Can we move these evaluators to  a class library as well?

Comment: Yes, of course you may move them to a separate class library.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no specific rule regarding this.

`IF`

you're going to reuse the helper function, abstract/separate it to another class.

`ELSE`

put it in the same class for better code cohesion and readability.